# How to find sum of even numbers in a list using recursion?

Tags: python, recursion, sum

```
def sum_evens_2d(xss):
    i = 0
    counter = 0
    while (i < len(xss)):
        if(xss[i]%2 == 0):
            counter += xss[i]   
            i= i+1
        else:
            i = i+1
    return(counter)
```

I am trying to find the sum of the evens in the list `xss`. My restrictions are that I can not use `sum()`, but recursion only.

Answer (score 1):

Provided code works fine.
So try to use `sum` as discribed below:

```
xss = range(5)
print sum(el for el in xss if el % 2 == 0)
```

Comment: You said that you can't use `sum()` cause you are getting an error. So there is a proper way how to use `sum()`.

Comment: no i can't use it because I am restricted not to use it by the professor.

Answer (score 1):

Just tested this one out, it should work:

```
def even_sum(a):
    if not a:
        return 0
    n = 0
    if a[n] % 2 == 0:
        return even_sum(a[1:]) + a[n]
    else:
        return even_sum(a[1:])

# will output 154
print even_sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 23, 55, 45, 66, 68])
```

Comment: `even_sum(range(10000))`

Answer (score 0):

if you cant use `sum` and must have recursion you can do:

```
def s(xss):
    if not xss:
        return 0 # for when the list is empty
    counter = 0 if xss[0] % 2 != 0 else xss[0]
    return counter + s(xss[1:])
```