# How to find a sum of even numbers in range recursively?

Tags: python, recursion

How can I write this function recursively?

```
def sum_even(n):
    total = 0
    for i in range(2, n+1,2):
        total = total + i
    return total
```

I've tried to write it recursively but failed since I just took the lesson.

Comment: "The sum of these numbers is equal to the first number _plus_ the sum of the rest of the numbers." Apply this logic and tweak it a bit to only check even indices and you'll arrive at a recursive solution.

Comment: Unrelated tip: `total = total + i` can be written as `total += i`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find sum of even numbers in a list using recursion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32936351/how-to-find-sum-of-even-numbers-in-a-list-using-recursion) Upvoted answer will work for `range` objects as well.

Answer (score 4):

Recursive functions can be difficult:

```
def sum_even(n):
    if n == 0:
        return n
    if n % 2 == 0:
        # Add the current number + the previous even number
        return n + sum_even(n - 2)  
    return add_even(n - 1) # If the number is odd, add the previous number
```

> ```
> i.e. sum_even(6)
>     n % 2 == 0:
>         return 6 + sum_even(4)
>         return 6 + 4 + sum_even(2)
>         return 6 + 4 + 2 + sum_even(0)
> Then n == 0
>         return 6 + 4 + 2 + return 0 
> 12
> ```

Similarly:

> ```
> sum_even(7)
> return sum_even(7 -1)
> return sum_even(6)
> ...
> return 12
> ```

Comment: FWIW though it probably doesn't matter in Python (as recursion is super slow anyway), in languages more suited to recursion you'd probably have a public "trampoline" which takes care of putting everything right (on an even `n`)) before calling the actual internal recursive function. It's also a common pattern in order to set up state for internal recursion e.g. you'd have an `_add_even(n, total)` and so your call would be `_add_even(n-2, total+n)` in order to be tail-recursive. And the terminal would return `total` rather than `n`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
def sum_even(n):
    if n%2 == 1:
        n = n-1
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    return n + sum_even(n-2)
```

Or,

```
def sum_even(n):
    if n%2 == 1:
        n = n-1
    return n + (n and sum_even(n-2))
```

`and` checks the first expression, if it finds `0` or `False` it does not evaluate the second expression, if first value is non-zero, in other words, not `False`, it returns whatever the second expression is.

Comment: Remove `total = 0` it's not being used

Comment: Ah, forgot. Tried using something else earlier :P

Comment: `sum_even2` isn't recursive :-P